# How add or remove object while iterating Collection in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to remove object while I am iterating through Collection. But I am getting exception. How can I achieve this?
Here is my code :

```
foreach (var gem in gems)
{
    gem.Value.Update(gameTime);

    if (gem.Value.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
    {
       gems.Remove(gem.Key); // I can't do this here, then How can I do?
       OnGemCollected(gem.Value, Player);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `foreach (var gem in gems.ToList())`

Comment: you cannot remove a element while iterating using foreach.use a simple for loop.foreach is not designed for this

Comment: what's exception message?

Comment: store the element keys you want to remove them after you've iterated through the list

Comment: I can't use gems.ToList(), because its Dictionary<key,value> type. And that's why having no idea how to use for. @CodeIgnoto: I tried that method, but it's not giving exact result what I want.

Comment: `gems` is a `Dictionary<Gem>` I take it?

Comment: `Dictionary` implements `IEnumerable<>` (this is why you can do a `foreach` through it). `ToList` is a LINQ extension method, if you add a `using System.Linq;` directive, it should work.

Comment: @HakooDesai Yes, &IV4 and @TimS are correct: `ToList()` will work because it produces a list of `KeyValuePair`, *not* a list of `Gem`.

Comment: @HakooDesai: what is the type of the Dictionary?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

foreach is designed for iterating over a collection without modifing it.

To remove items from a collection while iterating over it use a for loop from the end to the start of it.

```
for(int i = gems.Count - 1; i >=0 ; i--)
{
  gems[i].Value.Update(gameTime);

  if (gems[i].Value.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
  {
      Gem gem = gems[i];
      gems.RemoveAt(i); // Assuming it's a List<Gem>
      OnGemCollected(gem.Value, Player);
  }
 }
```

If it's a `dictionary<string, Gem>` for example, you could iterate like this:

```
foreach(string s in gems.Keys.ToList())
{
   if(gems[s].BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
   {
     gems.Remove(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: @MatthewWatson: In that case, if we assume that the key is also available in the value as a property, we can very well iterate through the dictionary using `dictionary.Values.ToList()` and for loop and then call `dictionary.Remove(item.Key);`

Comment: @saravanan Looking at the OP's code, it seems that the key is separate from the value.

Comment: Why this easy one didn't come in my mind!!! Thanks guys for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: It's even easier just to use `foreach (var gem in gems.ToList())` as suggested in the very first comment. You would just have needed to add `.ToList()` as noted, and it would just all work without you changing any other code! You seemed to think it wouldn't work, but that means you didn't try it because it definitely does work.

Comment: Looping through it backwards is really clever! I usually loop forwards and decrement whenever I remove something from a list. That is a lot more elegant.

Comment: `foreach (var gem in gems.ToList())` is certainly the easiest solution with the least amount of code changes. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

The *easiest* way is to do what @IV4 suggested:

```
foreach (var gem in gems.ToList())
```

The `ToList()` will convert the Dictionary to a list of `KeyValuePair`, so it will work fine.

The only time you wouldn't want to do it that way is if you have a big dictionary from which you are only removing relatively few items and you want to reduce memory use.

Only in that case would you want to use one of the following approaches:

---

Make a list of the keys as you find them, then have a separate loop to remove the items:

```
List<KeyType> keysToRemove = new List<KeyType>();

foreach (var gem in gems)
{
    gem.Value.Update(gameTime);

    if (gem.Value.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
    {
        OnGemCollected(gem.Value, Player);
        keysToRemove.Add(gem.Key);
    }
}

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
    gems.Remove(key);
```

(Where `KeyType` is the type of key you're using. Substitute the correct type!)

Alternatively, if it is important that the gem is removed *before* calling `OnGemCollected()`, then (with key type `TKey` and value type `TValue`) do it like this:

```
var itemsToRemove = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();

foreach (var gem in gems)
{
    gem.Value.Update(gameTime);

    if (gem.Value.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
        itemsToRemove.Add(gem);
}

foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    gems.Remove(item.Key);
    OnGemCollected(item.Value, Player);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, a foreach is designed purely for iterating over a collection without modifying it as [per the documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the desired information, but should not be used to change the contents
>   of the collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.

in order to do this you would need to use a [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) (storing the items of the collection you need to remove) and remove them from the collection afterwards.

However if you are using a `List<T>` you could do this:

```
lines.RemoveAll(line => line.FullfilsCertainConditions());
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through all the answers, and being equally good. I faced a challenge where I had to modify a List and what I ended up doing worked quite well for me. So just in case anyone finds it useful. Can someone provide me feedback on how efficient it might be.

```
Action removeFromList;
foreach(var value in listOfValues){
    if(whatever condition to remove is){
        removeFromList+=()=>listOfValues.remove(value);
    }
}
removeFromList?.Invoke();
removeFromList = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the for loop instead of the foreach loop. Please refer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/8975c43f-c329-4b95-9c42-9261869bf7c3/)

Comment: No, removing would mess up the indexing.

Comment: It would work if you went backwards through the list. But it's a moot point because the OP is using a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Collections support foreach statement using Enumarator. Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an InvalidOperationException. 
Use for loop for collection modifying.