# Delete item in nested collections of Nth level

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm having trouble trying to delete a item inside a tree structured object.

My object is as below

```
TreeNode
{
    string name;
    ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children;
}
```

I thought if I recursively process through the tree and find my node and delete it but I ran into trouble.

I did something along the lines of

Updated:

```
DeleteNode(ObservableCollection<TreeNode> children, TreeNode nodetodelete)
{
    if(children.remove(nodetodelete))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
            DeleteNode(child, nodetodelete);
        }
    }
}
```

I realize while I was writing the code that I would eventually run into manipulation exception while iterating through a collection that has a chance of being changed.
I could build a giant change of for loops since I know exactly the max deep length(which I did for a place holder) but that seems really bad. . . .
Can anyone point me in a better general direction. I kind of wonder if my data structure is the cause of this.

Update:

This will look awful and kinda of code smell but I got the recursion to "work"
by throw a exception when I find my node.

```
DeleteNode(children, nodetodelete)
    {
        if(children.remove(nodetodelete)
        {
            throw FoundException();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var child in children)
            {
                DeleteNode(child, nodetodelete)
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way of breaking out of a recursion.

Comment: Do you know in advance that the node will only appear once in the tree?

Comment: @Andrew if you are talking about duplicates there can be duplicate since at the certain level I have a place holder node to group together items.

Comment: Can you post your actual, exact code? What you've posted here won't even compile.

Comment: I think I saw someone post the answer but it was removed that a collection can't be manipulated in a foreach loop. I wish the person didn't remove his comment so I could give him credit. . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How add or remove object while iterating Collection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497028/how-add-or-remove-object-while-iterating-collection-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would deal with this by making a small change to my design (assuming the snippet in your question is pseudocode for a class):

```
TreeNode
{
    string name;
    TreeNode Parent;
    ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children;

    public void Delete()
    {
        Parent.Children.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

This makes a little bit more work for you maintaining an extra reference when manipulating your object graph, but saves you a lot of effort and code when doing things like deletes as you can see above.

You haven't shown how you're constructing `TreeNode`s, but I'd make the parent and a collection for the children arguments of the constructor.

Comment: A very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can safely iterate over the collection of children nodes and remove them, as long as you don't change the original collection. This can be done by creating an array of the collection and iterating over that instead.

```
DeleteNode(ObservableCollection<TreeNode> children, TreeNode nodetodelete)
{
    if (children.remove(nodetodelete))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var child in children.ToArray())
        {
            // If anything is deleted in the collection, it will not break the iteration here, as we are iterating over an Array and not "children"
            DeleteNode(child, nodetodelete);
        }
    }
}
```

This will create a new collection for you to iterate over. If a child node is deleted from `children`, the foreach loop will not throw an exception. That is because the original collection was changed, while we iterate over a secondary collection.