# MVC 5 Entity Framework 6 - deleting nested / hierarchical data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, asp.net-mvc-5, hierarchical-data

i've run into some trouble, when playing around with hierarchical data and trying to delete a node that has children.

I have set up a sample tree similar to [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management) and decorated the ul-li items with a little bit of bootstrap (add, delete and edit icons).

I'm struggeling now at the recursive deletion, as i am using an IEnumerable  (Children), which is the inverse result of parentNodeID. So when deleting a node, the children were updated and the system throws an enumeration error (collection has changed). I had such an error a few years ago, but i don't remember, how i fixed it. Any advice?

So here is what i got:

**~/Models/Tree.cs**

```
public class Tree
{
    [Key]
    public int NodeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Element name")]
    public string NodeName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Element identifier")]
    public string NodeIdentifier { get; set; }

    public int? ParentNodeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Tree Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tree> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**~/Controllers/TreesController.cs**

```
// Partial - only Delete Actions

// GET: Trees/Delete/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Tree tree = await db.Trees.FindAsync(id);
    if (tree == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    if (tree.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.HasChildren = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.HasChildren = false;
    }

    return View(tree);
}

// POST: Trees/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Tree tree = await db.Trees.FindAsync(id);
    DeleteRecursive(tree);
    db.Trees.Remove(tree);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public void DeleteRecursive(Tree tree)
{
    foreach(var child in tree.Children)
    {
        DeleteRecursive(child);
    }
    db.Trees.Remove(tree);
}
```

**~/Views/Trees/Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="container">
@helper BuildTree(IEnumerable<MVCMusicStore.Models.Tree> tree, int? parentID = null)
{
    var nodes = tree.Where(t => t.ParentNodeID == parentID).OrderBy(n => n.NodeIndexOrder);
    if (nodes.Any())
    {
        if (nodes.First().ParentNodeID == null)
        {
                <ul id="tree">
                    @foreach (var node in nodes)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @node.NodeIndexOrder - @node.NodeName &nbsp; <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Trees",new { id = node.NodeID })" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Bearbeiten"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>&nbsp; <a href="@Url.Action("Delete","Trees",new { id = node.NodeID })" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Löschen"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                            @BuildTree(tree, node.NodeID)
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
        }
        else
        {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var node in nodes)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @node.NodeIndexOrder - @node.NodeName &nbsp; <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Trees",new { id = node.NodeID })" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Bearbeiten"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>&nbsp; <a href="@Url.Action("Delete","Trees",new { id = node.NodeID })" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Löschen"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                            @BuildTree(tree, node.NodeID)
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
        }         
    }
    else
    {

        <p>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Create","Trees", new { parentNodeID = parentID })" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Neu"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
        </p>
    }
 }

@BuildTree(Model,null)
</div>
```

**Edit - Solution:**

```
public void DeleteRecursive(Tree tree)
{
    foreach(var child in tree.Children.ToArray<Tree>())
    {
        DeleteRecursive(child);
    }
    db.Trees.Remove(tree);
}
```

Using an array to delete from does not alter the original collection.

[Credits to Johnathon Sullinger: Delete item in nested collections of Nth level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30690013/5904385)

Comment: Collection has changed? Try using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop in the `DeleteRecursive` method.

Comment: Ah, I have a better solution, than using a for-loop (which is kinda old-skool imho).

Comment: What's old-school about `for`? Now you create an array that you don't need. Anyway, if you solve your own issue, it's alright to write an answer to your own question and even to mark it as accepted in due time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void DeleteRecursive(Tree tree)
{
    foreach(var child in tree.Children.ToArray<Tree>())
    {
        DeleteRecursive(child);
    }
    db.Trees.Remove(tree);
}
```

Using an array to delete from does not alter the original collection.